# How do I prevent Visual Studio from loading a PDB from Temporary ASP.NET Files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis-express, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on a multi-project solution in Visual Studio 2015 Professional that includes some libraries and an ASP.NET Web MVC application on a system used by multiple developers.

**Problem**
When I set a breakpoint and run the web application with debugging, IISExpress starts but the breakpoint is disabled with the following message.

[image: Screenshot of the message explaining why the breakpoint is disabled.]

When I check the Modules window it shows that symbols have been loaded for all the projects in the solution from various folders under this location `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

**What I've Tried**

- Clean Solution > Rebuild > Debug
- Manually Delete all `bin` and `obj` folders > Rebuild > debug
- Configuring symbols to not be automatically loaded and tried to load the symbols after the web application is already running.
- Verified that `Optimize Code` is not checked
- Verified that `Enable Just My Code` is checked
- Import Export Settings > Reset All Settings
- Installed Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and tried all of the above steps again
- Project Properties > Web > Clicked on the `Create Virtual Directory` button
- Deleted all files and folders under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`, `%AppData%\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`, and `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Web Sites` > changed the port number in the `Project Url` on the Web tab of the Project Properties

**Question**

How can I get Visual Studio to load the symbols from the project bin folder like it should be doing to begin with?

Comment: So, what is your actual problem?

Comment: the fact that i cannot debug because visual studio loads invalid symbols from anywhere but the projects outputs

Comment: Another possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821377/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-a-copy-of-file-was-found-in-dll-file

Comment: not a duplicate of the no symbols question

Comment: This is indeed very similar to the question suggested by @mxmissile. I have now tried the only step from that questions discussion i had yet to try and it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here're two tips you may try:

1.For the project where you set the breakpoints, right-click `project=>Properties=>Build tab(Debug Configuration)=>Advanced=>Set the Debug information` to `Full`

2.Empty the [Symbol cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019#configure-symbol-locations-and-loading-options), turn off [shadow copying](http://faithlife.codes/blog/2013/05/using-native-dlls-from-asp-net-apps/) to force it to load assemblies from your `bin` folder instead of `Temporary Asp.net Files` folder when running the application.(It will load xx.dll from bin, but I'm not certainly sure it will also load pdb from bin...)

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Technically this solved the question I asked because it's loading the pdb from the bin folder now. The new issue is that even though the Modules windows should the symbols loaded from the bin folder and I have done multiple Clean and multiple Rebuild operations it says it still will not hit my breakpoint because of different source version.

Comment: Disregard Last . The new issue was haste. I was looking at the wrong file after the this change. I can now debug normally.

Comment: It seems that new issue in your first comment is now resolved? If so, that's quite good news :) If it still exists, feel free to let me know!